# IE - Vanishing Nav

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a fairly simple responsive drop down menu. All looks good in Chrome and Firefox but in IE (10 and down) the menu is vanishing at a certain point.

I can't quite figure this one out I believe it's something to do with my jQuery when the window is resized.

I've created a JSFiddle but can't test it as my IE10 is crashing on me.

http://jsfiddle.net/9LX8L/

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<header>

<nav> <div class="menu-primary-navigation-container"><ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu" style="display: block;"><li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-6"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-45"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/category/tutorials/">Tutorials</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-46"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/category/tutorials/css3/">CSS3</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-47"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/category/tutorials/html5/">HTML5</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-48"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/category/tutorials/jquery/">jQuery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-49"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/category/tutorials/php/">PHP</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/contribute/">Contribute</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/contact/">Contact</a></li></ul></div><ul id="user-info"><li>Hey, Name</li>
            <li> <img alt="Avatar" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/90391e1d82af6445f9af05ba5495da59?s=48&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D48&amp;r=G" class="avatar avatar-48 photo" height="48" width="48">               </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://kodeable.com/wp/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fkodeable.com%2Fwp%2Fhtml-and-css-for-beginners-part-i%2F&amp;_wpnonce=e198305054" title="Logout" id="logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul> 
</nav>

<a href="http://www.kodeable.com"><img src="/wp/wp-content/themes/kodeable/images/logo.png" alt="Kodeable Logo" class="logo" height="55" width="312"></a>

</header>
```

Sorry it's a bit messy (this is directly from WordPress)

CSS:

```
/** ==============================================================
* Navigation
* ================================================================*/

header nav {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3ea49b;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
}

header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 24px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

    nav ul:after {
        clear: both;
        content: "";
        display: block;
    }

    header nav ul li {
        background: #fff;
        float: left;
        height: 48px;
    }

        nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }

        header nav ul li a:hover,
        header nav ul li.current-menu-item a,
        header nav ul li.current-menu-parent,
        header nav ul li.current-menu-parent a {
            background-color: #ef6f68;
            color: #fff;
        }

            header nav ul li.current-menu-parent ul li a {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #959595;
            }

                header nav ul li.current-menu-parent ul li.current-menu-item a {
                    background-color: #ef6f68;
                    color: #fff;
                }

            header nav ul li a:hover,
            header nav ul li.current-menu-item ul a:hover,
            header nav ul li.current-menu-parent a:hover,
            header nav ul li.current-menu-parent ul li.current-menu-item a:hover {
                background-color: #ef6f68;
                color: #fff;
            }

        header nav ul li a {
            color: #959595;
            display: block;
            padding: 14px 13px;
        }

            header nav ul li a:first-child {
                margin-left: 0;
            }

    header nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
    }

        nav ul ul li {
            float: none;
            position: relative;
        }

            header nav ul li.current-menu-item ul a {
                background: #fff;
            }

        nav ul ul ul {
            left: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
        }

ul.sub-menu {
    border: 2px solid #3ea49b;
        border-top: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-primary-navigation-container {
    float: left;
}

#user-info {
    float: right;
}

    #user-info li {
        float: left;
    }

        #user-info li:first-child {
            padding: 14px 13px;
        }

    #logout {
        background-color: #ef6f68;
        color: #fff;
        float: right;
        padding: 14px 13px;
        margin-right: 24px;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 870px) {

    .menu-primary-navigation-container {
        background: url(images/menu-icon.png) 2px 2px no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 48px;
        margin-left: 24px;
        width: 48px;
    }

        .menu-primary-navigation-container ul {
            display: none;
            margin-top: 48px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            padding: 0;
        }

            .menu-primary-navigation-container ul li {
                height: auto;
            }

            .menu-primary-navigation-container ul li a {
                background: #eee;
                clear: both;
                min-width: 200px;
            }

            .menu-primary-navigation-container ul li ul {
                border: none;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                position: static;
            }

                .menu-primary-navigation-container ul li ul li:first-child {
                    border-top: 2px solid #76c2bb;
                }

                    .menu-primary-navigation-container ul li ul li a {
                        background: #fff;
                        padding-left: 24px;
                    }

                        .menu-primary-navigation-container ul li ul li a:hover {
                            background: #ef6f68;
                        }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 470px) {

    ul#user-info li:first-child {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if(!jQuery.browser.mobile && $(window).width() < 870) {
            if(e.target.className !== "menu-primary-navigation-container") {
                if($('#menu-primary-navigation').is(":visible")) {
                    if(e.target.className !== "menu") {
                        $("#menu-primary-navigation").hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('.menu-primary-navigation-container').click(function() {

        if($(window).width() < 870) {

            $this = $(this);

            if($('#menu-primary-navigation').is(":visible")) {
                $this.children('ul').hide();
            } else {
                $this.children('ul').show();
            }

        }

    });

    $(window).resize(function() {

        if(!jQuery.browser.mobile) {
            if($(window).width() > 870){
                $('#menu-primary-navigation').show();
            } else {
                $('#menu-primary-navigation').hide();
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle.net too

Comment: Or at least a link to the site in question

Comment: try `overflow:auto;` for `header` and `nav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this now - simple solution was to change $(window).width() to $(document).width() in my jQuery code.